# Embed custom meta-data (bounding boxes) into HLS video stream

Tags: machine-learning, ffmpeg, computer-vision, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I'd like to **embed bounding boxes, labels, etc. into live video stream** to optionally draw them thereafter on the client-side in web-browser and looking for a way how to do.

Could you please give me a hint how to insert the meta-data "on fly" and which player might be used for it?

Comment: mpeg transport streams (HLS) can carry various stuff. you just have to learn more about the format.